# Joomla Mootools menu conflict with Facebook SDK Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, joomla, mootools

I am currently developing a website using Joomla (latest version) and heavily customised Valera template.  The template includes a Mootools dropdown menu which works fine until I attempt to embed the Facebook Page Plugin javascript.

The menu will open the parent menu item and then freeze in open position.  Each time the menu is moused-over Chrome Console reports:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "://gowercamping.co.uk" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "://staticxx.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set
>   "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access
>   did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow
>   access.       @   mootools-core.js:5063

I have checked settings in developers.facebook.com and domain and URL settings are correct.

I have tested the script with an unedited version of the template and it does not produce this error.  I have also contacted the support forum for the template but so far no joy. www.joomlage.com/forum/5-commercial-joomla-templates-support/5004-joomlage0075-valera-mootools-dropdown-menu-conflict-with-facebook-javascript#9564

Working menu without Facebook SDK JS: http://gowercamping.co.uk/joomla3-3/
Broken menu with Facebook SDK JS: http://gowercamping.co.uk/joomla3-3/things-to-do.

Chrome Console throws error, referencing CSS rules.

```js
  var searchStyles = function(rules){
   Array.each(rules, function(rule, i){
    if (rule.media){
```

I hope someone can take a look for me as I am struggling with this one.

Edit: found this, might test it tomorrow as it seems similar: www.jfusion.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=3204

Cheers,

Stella

Comment: If you wrote neither plugin, it may be difficult for you to determine where the problem lies and which, if either, plugin can be modified to account for it - you may need to talk to the author of the plugins for assistance